# Fetch nested attributes of json to csv using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

For the json file, not able to extract nested attributes.

```
 {
  "Includes": {
    "Employees": {
      "14": {
        "name": "john",
        "age": 12,
        "activity": {
          "Count": 3502,
          "RatingValue": 5
        }
      },
      "17": {
        "name": "smith",
        "age": 23,
        "activity": {
          "Count": 232,
          "RatingValue": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting output as

14,john,12,3502,5

17,smith,23,232,5

I have written aggregate function it is not working

```
db.details.aggregate([
    { $unwind:"$Includes.Employees"},
    { $project : { name : "$Employees.name" , age:"$Employees.age", count:"$Employees.Count", RatingValue:"$Employees.RatingValue", _id:0} },
    { $out: "output" }
])
```

Here 14 and 17 can be dynamic.

Comment: **$unwind** used to handle array, not sub-document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation pipeline can not handle this issue. Use JS:

Step 1 : covert data and save into a new collection, named as "result"

```
db.details.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var Employees = doc.Includes.Employees;
    if (Employees) {
        for ( var key in Employees) {
            var Employee = Employees[key];
            if (Employee) {
                var item = {
                    id : key,
                    name : Employee.name,
                    age : Employee.age
                };
                var activity = Employee.activity;
                if (activity) {
                    item.Count = activity.Count;
                    item.RatingValue = activity.RatingValue;
                }
                db.result.insert(item);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Setp 2: use "mongoexport"

```
mongoexport -d mydb -c result --csv --fields id,name,age,Count,RatingValue --out output.csv
```

Comment: Not able to print in csv file, facing issues only headers are printed.

mongoexport -d mydb -c result --fields name,age,count,ratingvalue --out output.csv

I want to store the output in csv with 2 rows